# How to test obtaining a list of files within a directory using RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm pretty new to the world of RSpec. I'm writing a RubyGem that deals with a list of files within a specified directory and any sub-directories. Specifically, it will use `Find.find` and append the files to an Array for later output.

I'd like to write a spec to test this behaviour but don't really know where to start in terms of faking a directory of files and stubbing `Find.find` etc. This is what little I have so far:

```
it "should return a list of files within the specified directory" do
end
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to test the library, but if you have a method like

```
def file_names
  files = []
  Find.find(Dir.pwd){|file| files << file}
  ........
end
```

you can stub the find method to return a list of files like so

```
it "should return a list of files within the specified directory" do
  Find.stub!(:find).and_return(['file1', 'file2'])
  @object.file_names
end
```

or if you want to set the expectation then you can do

```
it "should return a list of files within the specified directory" do
  Find.should_receive(:find).and_return(['file1', 'file2'])
  @object.file_names
end
```

Comment: Great, thanks nas. And a good point about not needing to test the library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [fakeFS](http://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) gem.